# Extract row data from query given a date and a common value in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_amount int NOT NULL, 
    the_date date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '200', '2/12/2019'), 
       ('LMUS01', '200', '2/11/2019'), 
       ('LMUS01', '300', '2/13/2019'), 
       ('LMUS02', '100', '2/10/2019'), 
       ('LMUS02', '150', '2/12/2019')
```

And I want the amount of the first day of LMUS01. When I try:

```
SELECT the_amount, MIN(the_date) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_id = 'LMUS01'
```

It tells me that `the_amount` must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. But the group must be `the_id`, and I tried:

```
SELECT the_amount, MIN(the_date) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_id = 'LMUS01' 
GROUP BY the_id
```

The result must be:

```
200, 2/11/2019
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Vote up for the effort in correcting small "mistakes" in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `LIMIT` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE the_id = 'LMUS01' 
ORDER BY the_date
LIMIT 1;
```

To get the earliest record for each ID, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_id) *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY the_id, the_date;
```

If you really wanted to make your original approach work with the `MIN` function, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE
    the_id = 'LMUS01' AND
    the_date = (SELECT MIN(the_date) FROM my_table WHERE the_id = 'LMUS01');
```

But, I would use one of the other methods first, which should perform better in Postgres.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen, just a question, why the MIN clause from a group doesn't index the row? Is that a rule in SQL?

Comment: @Manu Check the update to my answer.  The `LIMIT` option might conceptually be closest to what you have in mind.  If you must use a `MIN` approach, then you can do so with a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option you can do with `min` function:

```
SELECT the_amount, the_date
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_id = 'LMUS1' --<< I have changed this because of varchar(5)
and the_date = (select min(the_date) 
                from my_table 
                WHERE the_id = 'LMUS1' ); --<< I have changed this because of varchar(5)
```

You have to understand that this will work:

```
select min(the_date) 
from my_table 
WHERE the_id = 'LMUS1';
```

And this will not:

```
select the_amount, min(the_date) 
from my_table 
WHERE the_id = 'LMUS1';
```

Because you have to put every column from the select clause in the group by clause if it is not a part of aggregation function. So this second example would work if you write it like this:

```
select the_amount, min(the_date) 
from my_table 
WHERE the_id = 'LMUS1'
group by the_amount;
```

But ofcourse that will not give you the wanted results...
[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f8bfd27a4c9d746bbc3c8ca37a30aefd) where you can see this examples in action.

Comment: Hello @VBoka, thank you for pointing out the flaws of my question, I fixed them to make the question helpful to others. I will investigate more on the "aggregation" subject you mention, because later I have to make a left join based on the "id".

Comment: You are welcome, I will remove that part of my answer then :)